# Connection between 2 PHYs - how?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, transformer, ethernet

I want to have a PHY-to-PHY Ethernet connection on the same PCB but cannot disable AN and Auto-MDIX (no register access available)?

Use capacitive coupling anyways or use magnetics instead? If magnetics is recommended in this scenario, is there a reference design and/or suggested magnetics?

[KSZ8864](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/KSZ8864CNX-RMNUB-Data-Sheet-00002229D.pdf) & [LAN9512](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002304A.pdf).

LAN9512i pin 52 to KSZ8864 pin 1

LAN9512i pin 53 to KSZ8864 pin 2

LAN9512i pin 55 to KSZ8864 pin 3

LAN9512i pin 56 to KSZ8864 pin 4

Comment: Are the PHYs required, or is the expectation more of a "MII-to-MII" connection, because the latter might be implemented in a small FPGA.

Comment: Which PHYs? Copper PHYs? What speeds they support?

Comment: the PHYs are https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/KSZ8864CNX-RMNUB-Data-Sheet-00002229D.pdf & https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002304A.pdf @SimonRichter. Can I connect the, LAN9512i pin 52 to KSZ8864 pin 1,
LAN9512i pin 53 to KSZ8864 pin 2,
LAN9512i pin 55 to KSZ8864 pin 3,
LAN9512i pin 56 to KSZ8864 pin 4.

Comment: @Justme, I have added the PHY's in the question. 100Mbps support. Can you please check

Comment: @Justme any idea on this?

Comment: @SimonRichter any idea on this?

Comment: No idea and not all PHYs support capacitive coupling so it may not be possible and finding the info if it supports or not can also be impossible to find.

Answer (score 0):

Microchip has app notes on both of those:

For the KSZ series: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/jp/AppNotes/jp578072.pdf

For the LAN series: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/cn/AppNotes/cn586761.pdf

You *really* want to force 100Base-T if you can due to its signalling schema.  10Base-T shouldn't negotiate because it should fail, but you are very much operating 10Base-T in a region that is not characterized.

Hope this helps.